# Decode Cyrillic url

Tags: php, url, decode

For example I have post name `%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2` it mus be `АРХИВ` , it's possible to decode to normal word this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy:

```
echo urldecode('%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2'); //=архив
```